# Deprecated methods are not struck through in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, deprecated, strikethrough

Methods annotated as `@Deprecated` do not show with a strikethrough in editor panes. It doesn't show up in the preview pane of the color scheme settings either (the lines "Deprecated symbol" and "Deprecated symbol marked for removal" are normal, even though `Strikeout` effect is selected).

[image: screenshot]

Deprecation inspections are turned on as well, and show up when running `Analyze` over a Java file. I've already tried changing the font from Fira Code to something else, and disabling font ligatures, but that didn't work.

This is on IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.2.4

Comment: There is this question from five years ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947327 - but none of the answers there helped in my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a bug when rendering texts. See [IDEA-198539](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198539)

Comment: Yep, it was this bug, adding `-Dide.text.effect.new.metrics=false` to VM options fixed it for now

Comment: This appears to be resolved as of build 183.4139.22 (October 30 2018)

Answer (score 1):

1. The correct usage is `@deprecated` (do not use capitalization)
2. Make sure the Java | Code maturity | **Deprecated API usage** inspection is enabled and this symbol usage is not fall into one of the *ignored* cases in the inspection options. Un-mark all the ignores there to make sure:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, all of the 'deprecated' inspections were already enabled to at least the Warning level, even after unticking all those Ignore checkboxes the problem persisted.

Comment: `@deprecated` is the javadoc tag. `@Deprecated` is the Java annotation. You should use both.